# SQL Query Performance DISTINCT IN

Tags: sql, distinct

I have one requirement in my project as follows :

There is a table like this :

```
UID       VER      STATUS  
--------------------------
DOC001    VER.1    N/A
DOC001    VER.2    N/A
DOC001    VER.3    N/A
DOC001    VER.4    N/A
DOC002    VER.1    N/A
DOC002    VER.2    N/A
DOC002    VER.3    N/A
DOC003    VER.1    N/A
DOC003    VER.2    N/A
DOC003    VER.3    N/A
DOC003    VER.4    N/A
DOC003    VER.5    N/A
DOC003    VER.6    N/A
```

I need to change the status of each version after doing some validation. In this process, if VER.2 of Doc, say DOC001 has failed, I need to update the status of remaining versions i.e. VER.3 and VER.4 to FAIL irrespective of validation.

For this, I wrote SQL queries using DISTINCT, IN, ORDER BY clauses which is very slow.
The real time time DB is quite big and has millions of rows which increases the pressure on me to improve the performance.

Your suggestions and help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Query optimization questions can be answered only if you provide the SQL and the corresponding explain plan. We cannot guess ;)

Comment: Try to run the query using `EXPLAIN SELECT [...]` Statement and have a look on the used index for your statement. You need to optimize your database tables and your query but please post your query, so we may have a look on what you are doing.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What indexes are defined? What statements are you using? All RDBMSs have an option to display the execution plan of a query. SQL Server even displays it visually by pressing a single button. Have you defined any indexes on the table that cover the fields you use in WHERE, DISTINCT, ORDER BY? No indexes means the server has to scan the entire table.